# Draw circle at cornor of svg dynamically

Tags: javascript, svg, svg.js

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cHUHc.png)
This image is generated by svg tool. i want to get coordinate of main svg where i can dynamically add  circle to simulate it like holes.the dimension of svg will dynamically change.

Comment: Your problem statement is not clear. Please provide some more information in the context. 1) Do you have access to reference of the  generetaed svg in DOM? 2) What have you tried so far?

Comment: Also: are you familiar with svg.js which you tagged there?

Comment: Yes i am,I am using Google svg-edit tool where i provided a button to add number of circle on svg on button click as you can see in image.now i want to calculate the position of coordinate  there i want to place this circle.